# Ember-cli unit tests with relationships 'needs'

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I am working on my unit tests and it feels like I am doing something incorrect. I have a 'main' object that has many relationships

```
author: belongsTo('person', { async: true }),
title: attr('string'),
category: belongsTo('category', { async: true }),
impact: belongsTo('impact', { async: true }),
status: attr('string'),
createdDate: attr('moment'),
submittedDate: attr('moment'),
authorOrg: belongsTo('organization', { async: true }),
locations: hasMany('location', { async: true }),
audits: hasMany('audit', { async: true })
```

And each time I work on the unit tests for its related items (`person`, `category`,`impact`), I'm having to reproduce all of the `needs` values that my 'main' object has. It just doesn't feel right for my location unit test to need `category` when it only cares about a string for its name and its relationship back to the 'main' object

```
// location/model-test.js
import {
  moduleForModel,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForModel('location', 'Location', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: ['model:main', 'model:person', 'model:category',
      'model:impact', 'model:organization', 'model:location']
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to build my unit tests to deal with the relationships?

I am on ember-cli 0.1.5, ember 1.9.1, and ember-data beta 14

Answer (score 1):

I have resorted to defining a wrapper function that adds a specifier to the module label and then I use this convenience function each time I want a new module:

```
var anotherModule = function(suffix) {
  moduleForModel('location', 'Location - ' + suffix, {
    needs: ['model:main', 'model:person', 'model:category',
      'model:impact', 'model:organization', 'model:location']
  });
};

anotherModule("module 1");
test("test 1.1", function() { });
test("test 1.1", function() { });

anotherModule("module 2");
test("test 2.1", function() { });
```